# Spilt data table into multiple data table on basis of dates in column

Tags: datatable

I have some specific issue with data table that i have to split it dynamically on the basis of dates which are in data table column.

for example:

[enter link description here](https://plus.google.com/photos/101957904473890909455/albums/5849968982763897505)

Now according to dates I should get 3 data tables having name respectively.

I could not Linq so how can resolve this problem????

Thnks.

Comment: lannguage ? code you've written so far ?

Answer (score 0):

you can sort the table according to the date column and then go over the rows data and create new table for every new date